# Communication from Angular module to app component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-components, angular-event-emitter

In my Angular client I have one module call library. It does CRUD transactions related to books. I have an alert component and service in app root. That alert component is nested as a view child in app-component. Therefore once I perform CRUD actions, I want to inform the service in root from my library module.

What is the easiest way to build that communication?

**AlertService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

//Alert service 

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AlertService {
  //Attributes
  show: boolean = false;
  type: string = 'info';
  message: string; 
  timeoutTimer: any; 

  //Constructor of the AlertService. 
  constructor() { }
  
  //Responsible for displaying the alert. 
  displayAlert(message: string, type: string = 'info', autohide: number = 5000) {
      this.show = true;
      this.message = message;
      this.type = type;
      
      //If timer is already available
      if (this.timeoutTimer) { 
          clearTimeout(this.timeoutTimer);
      }
      
      //If autohide is there then start the timeout 
      if (autohide) {
          setTimeout(() => {this.close()}, autohide);
      }
  }
  
  //Responsible for setting the show attribute false. 
  close() {
      this.show = false;
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to select an example from the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components) to explain this.

```
export class HeroListComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Hero[] = [];
  selectedHero: Hero | undefined;

  constructor(private service: HeroService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.heroes = this.service.getHeroes();
  }

  selectHero(hero: Hero) { this.selectedHero = hero; }
}
```

The `constructor(private service: HeroService)` is where you injected the service into the component. You can now access all methods of HeroService inside of your component. So, you would want to make a method in your service, something like `alert(message) { doSomething }`, and then you call `service.alert("Hello")` in the component, usually during a method that is doing a CRUD operation. See how the ngOnInit() function is using the service and one of its methods to update data in the component.

Comment: I understand your solution but that is not really my problem. I am sorry if I misunderstood your ides, my problem is that I am inside the module. There I cannot import a my service which is in root directory. If there is a way to import alert service from root to module then that would be a solution.

Comment: You might want to think about moving application logic out of the module and into the service or the component. NgModules typically define a group of other things (components, services, classes). Services are imported into components, and that is where they actually "do work". Services do not do work inside of modules.